# Join two lines in a same file with similar content

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to solve this specific problem in shell but I didn't get anything yet...please help!

I have one file.txt with more than 30K of lines with this format:

```
phoneNumber|ID|CITY|NAME|SURNAME1|SURNAME2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
```

For example I have this input file:

```
 558000003|11111113B|LONDON|NAME FAKE3|SURNAME FAKE3|SURNAMEFAKE_3|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 558000002|11111112B|LONDON|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 558000001|11111111B|LONDON|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 558000003|11111113B|BERLIN|NAME FAKE3|SURNAME FAKE3|SURNAMEFAKE_3|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 557000002|11111112A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 557000001|11111111A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
```

As you can see, line 1 and 4 are similar, but the third column. What I would like to obtain is this output:

```
 558000003|11111113B|LONDON,BERLIN|NAME FAKE3|SURNAME FAKE3|SURNAMEFAKE_3|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 558000002|11111112B|LONDON|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 558000001|11111111B|LONDON|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 557000002|11111112A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 557000001|11111111A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
```

I don't care about order in output lines. I'm trying to get this with command "awk" in an script shell, but nothing that works...

Could it be possible to join lines if there is a coincidence in one field?

Comment: What are the unique fields to compare? Just the 1st?

Comment: The 2nd one, ID, is the only unique one in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the combination of $1 and $2 create the unique key:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    key = $1 SUBSEP $2
    keys[key]
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( !seen[key,i,$i]++ && ((key,i) in fld) ) {
            fld[key,i] = fld[key,i] "," $i
        }
        else {
            fld[key,i] = $i
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", fld[key,i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}
' file
 558000002|11111112B|LONDON|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 558000001|11111111B|LONDON|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 558000003|11111113B|LONDON,BERLIN|NAME FAKE3|SURNAME FAKE3|SURNAMEFAKE_3|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 557000002|11111112A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
 557000001|11111111A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
```

Comment: Wow, almost get it!! But I proved it and doesn't gave me the same output as you, I obtain this:
 558000003|11111113B|,LONDON|NAME FAKE3|SURNAME FAKE3|SURNAMEFAKE_3|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
Could it be because of whitespaces?

Comment: No. If you run it against the input file you provided it WILL produce the output you specified. If it doesn't produce the expected output then you are not running it on the input you specified. Off the top of my head I suspect that early in your input file you have a line that starts with the 2 key values but has a 3rd field that is empty. I tweaked it a little just now to work for differences in any field, not just the 3rd field, but that's unrelated to your comment.

Comment: Ok, then for sure it has been my mistake. I'm going to review it, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Call me fool, but I couldn't reproduce your output. Could you please give me also the complete "awk" command in only one line?

Comment: The above IS the complete awk command. Why would you want it crunched onto one line??? Stick it in a file and execute it as a shell script if you like or stick the awk part (between the `'`s) in a file and execute it as `awk -f scriptfile file`.

Comment: Also - check if your input file has spurious control characters in it, e.g. the control-Ms that Windows tools generously donate to files for no additional charge. Run `cat -v file` to see them and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them if present.

Comment: Finally - copy/paste the text you provided in your question as the sample input file into a file. Run my tool on it. Does it produce the expected output? Presumably the answer is yes so then diff that input file against the other input file you have been trying it on so far.

Comment: could it be possible that you incluide a pseudocode or explanation of what it exactly makes in each line? Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to do that. Try to figure it out yourself from the man page and the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins and if you have any SPECIFIC questions then post a new question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway for the library recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

awk way

Will print it all at the first occurence of key(may be able to be improved/shortened)

```
 awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" 'b[$2]{split(a[$2],c,"|");gsub(/.*/,c[3]",&",$3)}{a[$2]=$0;if(!b[$2])d[NR]=$2;b[$2]++}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(d[i])print a[d[i]]}' file
```

Broken up a bit

```
 awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" '
      b[$2]{split(a[$2],c,"|")
            gsub(/.*/,c[3]",&",$3)
     }
     {a[$2]=$0
     if(!b[$2])d[NR]=$2
     b[$2]++
     }
     END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(d[i])print a[d[i]]}' file
```

If you have trouble with single character array names

```
 awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" '
      Count[$2]{split(Line[$2],Arr,"|")
            gsub(/.*/,Arr[3]",&",$3)
     }
     {Line[$2]=$0
     if(!Count[$2])Key[NR]=$2
     Count[$2]++
     }
     END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(Key[i])print Line[Key[i]]}' file
```

#### Output

```
558000003|11111113B|LONDON,BERLIN|NAME FAKE3|SURNAME FAKE3|SURNAMEFAKE_3|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
558000002|11111112B|LONDON|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
558000001|11111111B|LONDON|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
557000002|11111112A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE2|SURNAME FAKE2|SURNAMEFAKE_2|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
557000001|11111111A|BERLIN|NAME FAKE1|SURNAME FAKE1|SURNAMEFAKE_1|NAME SURNAME1 SURNAME2|
```

Comment: If arrays a, b, c, and d were given more meaningful names it would improve readability considerably. A little white space in statements like `if(!b[$2])d[NR]=$2` wouldn't hurt either. Be careful with tests like `b[$2]` as they are not the same as `$2 in b` and can produce unexpected results when `b[$2]` holds a value that evaluates to numeric zero or is the null string - I can't tell if that'll be an issue in this case or not as I cant be bothered to figure out what the arrays do (hence my lazy request for meaningful names!).

Comment: `b[$2]` contains the number of them seen so i don't think it will be a problem and the d holds the NR. As for the names, i find it just as hard to figure out everything in your answer. And i think spacing is a preference and that the broken up one is quite easy to understand personally.

Comment: Whatever issues my answer has aside, giving your arrays meaningful names made a HUGE difference in the readability. Thanks!